# Make Arbitrary Table Column Width Equal to Space Available

Tags: html, css

The scenario is I want a table column to consume all of the available with -- nothing more and nothing less. This is similar to using `table td:last-child{width:100%}` except the column many not be the last.

My sample code below demonstrates what I have so far.

The first table shows the result when the data fits comfortably.

The second table shows what happens when the column whose width I want to vary has too much data. What it does is it pushes the last column over. What I want it to do is to have a width still equal to the available space after accounting for the other columns and for the excess text to be treated as overflow, which means it should be hidden.

Please note that in the real-life scenario the table can be resized, so any solution that relies on setting the columns width to a value or percentage will probably not suffice.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```html
<style>
    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        font: 16px arial;
        border: 1px solid steelblue;
        background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }

    .variCell {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }


    .orderCell {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 65px;
        text-align: right;
    }


    table {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    thead {
        position: relative;
        display: table-header-group;
        height: 25px;
        max-height: 25px;
        background-color: #93aed2;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 25px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    tbody {
        position: relative;
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    Col 1
                </td>
                <td class="variCell">
                    Col 2
                </td>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    Col 3
                </td>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="variCell">
                    Please use available space only.
                </td>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    100
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    Col 1
                </td>
                <td class="variCell">
                    Col 2
                </td>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    Col 3
                </td>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="variCell">
                    Please use available space only. Do not push the next column out of the table.
                </td>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    100
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to have a fixed `width:500px` to `.container` or you can make it 100%?

Comment: That was for demonstration purposes. In the real-world application the container width varies.  That is partially -- but not wholly -- why I am looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `table-layout:fixed` for the `table` and `white-space: break-word;` for fixed columns and stop table from expanding.

```css
.container {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        font: 16px arial;
        border: 1px solid steelblue;
        background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }

    .variCell {
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .variCell span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    
    .orderCell {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 65px;
        text-align: right;
    }


    table {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    thead {
        position: relative;
        display: table-header-group;
        height: 25px;
        max-height: 25px;
        background-color: #93aed2;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 25px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    tbody {
        position: relative;
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    Col 1
                </td>
                <td class="variCell">
                    Col 2
                </td>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    Col 3
                </td>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="variCell">
                    <span>Please use available space only. Do not push the next column out of the table.</span>
                </td>
                <td class="orderCell">
                    100
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The table-layout setting seems to have no effect. Also I want to display only one row of text and have the rest treated as overflow hidden. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Then what you'd really want to do is have your text inside a `span` that you can target and make use of `position: absolute;` to be able to make the text appear at a fixed place. I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK, that appears to be about as good a solution as there is. Thanks!